# Return a list of documents from CosmosDB WHERE to filter nested data

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to select `"docType" : "offer"` from my cosmosdb collection, where the company ID matches the users company ID.

**Sample CosmosDB Document**

```
{
    "id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",
    "company": [
        {
            "id": "D4B7B6CA-116C-452C-AEC7-58999567CD8Z",
            "name": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": "D4B7B6CA-116C-452C-AEC7-58999567CD8C",
            "name": "B"
        }
    ],
    "docType": "offer"
}
```

**Query**: Here is my current query, but it does not work as a invalid  `&&`
to with `bool` and `IEnumerable`

```
var queryOffers = from doc in _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Offer>(collectionUri, DefaultOptions)
            where doc.docType == "offer" && doc.Companies.Any(i => i.id == user.company.companyId)
            select doc;
```

Note my cosmosdb is using the SQL API.

Comment: I don't believe that `Any` is supported by Document DB.

Comment: I think you can run a straight query that does something like this:  `select * from c JOIN co in c.company where c.docType = 'offer' and co.id IN ("your_co_id")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var queryOffers = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<Offer>(collectionUri, DefaultOptions)
            .Where(doc => doc.docType == "offer")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(c => c.Company.Any(i => i.id == id));
```

Comment: That's going to pull all the data down to the client, and then apply the where clause though, right?

Answer (score 0):

I had come across a similar problem where I needed to use a nested `Any()/Contains()` inside an existing Lambda expression. I had to actually add an additional redundant field to be able to query, since `Any()/Contains()` isn't supported this way.

Have a look at this yourself: [Use Linq.Any() inside a Linq.Where() on CosmosDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229108/use-linq-any-inside-a-linq-where-on-cosmosdb)

For your case, you will need an additional `List` of `companyIds` and therafter you will be able to nest `Any()` inside the `where()`