# Azure CosmosDB SDK runtime exception: Method 'Any' is not supported

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I get a runtime exception with the stacktrace as below. It seems it doesn't include any information about where it happens in our application code. Any ideas on what might cause this exception? We don't use 'Any' in our application code.

Let me know what else info that could be useful to figure it out.

```
{
  "Exception": {
    "Type": "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException",
    "Message": "Method 'Any' is not supported., Windows/10.0.14393 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.1.3",
    "StackTrace": "
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ArrayBuiltinFunctions.Visit(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.BuiltinFunctionVisitor.VisitBuiltinFunctionCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCallScalar(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarExpression(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarLambda(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitWhere(ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.SqlTranslator.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.HandleMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryEvaluator.Evaluate(Expression expression)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<CreateRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteOnceAsync>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<ExecuteInternalAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteInternalAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__42.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.ProxyDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "InnerExceptions": []
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to find the location of the exception by checking the box "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the Visual Studio Debug > Windows > Exception Settings

Comment: Could you please provide your code?  Besides, is that your use Azure CosmosDB .Net V2 SDK?

Comment: @ jim I can’t provide the code, I don’t know where it’s thrown and that’s the problem. @ crowcoder: mm, it happens in production, I haven’t been able to reproduce in debug mode.

Comment: Have you referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839854/c-sharp-linq-any-not-working-on-documentdb-createdocumentquery?

Comment: @JimXu No I haven't, thanks. That's probably the same issue as we have. Now comes the very tedious and not so easy task of figuring out where in our code the problem lies.

Comment: @Anton Do you have any update?